# Scanning double with Scanner in Java from Console

Tags: java

I want to read a double number from standard input, but I always get this exception:

> java.util.InputMismatchException

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    }
}
```

If the input is integer it's okay, but when double, I get the exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
>       at ScanDouble.main(ScanDouble.java:10)

Comment: How does your input look like?

Comment: whats your input , what is the exception ?

Comment: My input is like: 10.0 

The exception is shown above.

Comment: When I run http://ideone.com/aILMkI with your input it does the right thing.

Comment: @sameerasy white space should be ignored.

Comment: I don't have spaces.

Comment: I would check your Locale. Some locales don't accept a `.` as a period.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  You were right. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think it is a Problem with the decimal separator. Try the input `10,0`

If you want to scan the value with dot, set the locale to locale UK:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useLocale(Locale.UK);
double d = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Double: " + d);
```